# How to resolve Laravel RuntimeException in Docker container

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I'm running PHP version 7.3 inside a Docker container, using the root user.

I can't run `composer upgrade` as it may break dependencies.

I can't tell what directory PHP is trying to access; I've tried to delete the `vendor` directory: that didn't help.

The issue is that when I run `php artisan -v common:create-phpunit-config` at the root directory (`/`) of my Ubuntu version 16.04 container, I get the error below;

> Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\RuntimeException  : The provided cwd "" does not exist.
>      `at /vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:334
>          330|             }
>          331|         }
>          332| 
>          333|         if (!is_dir($this->cwd)) {
>   334|             throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('The provided cwd "%s" does not exist.', $this->cwd));
>          335|         }
>          336| 
>          337|         $this->process = proc_open($commandline, $descriptors, $this->processPipes->pipes, $this->cwd, $envPairs, $options);
>          338|`

Expected behaviour:

To execute `php artisan -v common:create-phpunit-config` with no errors.

composer.json file:

```
{
   "name": "test/proj",
   "description": "Test application",
   "type": "project",
   "license": "proprietary",
   "require": {
      "php": ">=7.2.1",
      "ext-SimpleXML": "*",
      "ext-bcmath": "*",
      "ext-dom": "*",
      "ext-filter": "*",
      "ext-hash": "*",
      "ext-json": "*",
      "ext-libxml": "*",
      "ext-openssl": "*",
      "ext-session": "*",
      "ext-soap": "*",
      "abraham/twitteroauth": "^1.0",
      "barryvdh/laravel-translation-manager": "^0.5.3",
      "beberlei/doctrineextensions": "^1.0",
      "bjeavons/zxcvbn-php": "^0.4.0",
      "browscap/browscap-php": "^4.1",
      "cloudipsp/php-sdk-v2": "^1.0",
      "doctrine/dbal": "^2.7",
      "fideloper/proxy": "~4.0",
      "gedmo/doctrine-extensions": "^2.4",
      "germey/geetest": "^3.0",
      "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
      "imangazaliev/didom": "^1.13",
      "irazasyed/laravel-gamp": "^1.3",
      "irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk": "^3.0",
      "laravel-doctrine/extensions": "^1.0",
      "laravel-doctrine/migrations": "^1.1",
      "laravel-doctrine/orm": "^1.4",
      "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
      "laravel/helpers": "^1.0",
      "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
      "laravelcollective/html": "^5.8",
      "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
      "myclabs/php-enum": "^1.7",
      "nesbot/carbon": "^2",
      "nwidart/laravel-modules": "^5.0",
      "paragonie/constant_time_encoding": "^2.2",
      "pda/pheanstalk": "~4.0",
      "phpseclib/phpseclib": "~2.0",
      "pragmarx/google2fa-laravel": "^0.2.0",
      "predis/predis": "^1.1",
      "propa/laravel-browscap": "^2.0",
      "ramsey/uuid": "^3.8",
      "sendpulse/rest-api": "^1.0",
      "sentry/sentry-laravel": "^1.0",
      "spatie/laravel-fractal": "^5.3",
      "symfony/finder": "^4.1",
      "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^3.4"
   },
   "require-dev": {
      "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2.4",
      "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.4",
      "dg/bypass-finals": "^1.1",
      "doctrine/coding-standard": "^6.0",
      "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
      "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
      "laravel/telescope": "^2.0",
      "mockery/mockery": "~1.0",
      "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
      "phpspec/prophecy": "^1.8.1",
      "phpunit/php-code-coverage": "^7.0.5",
      "phpunit/phpunit": "^8",
      "psalm/plugin-laravel": "^0.4.0",
      "psalm/plugin-phpunit": "^0.6.0",
      "sebastian/global-state": "^3",
      "vimeo/psalm": "^3.4",
      "mysite/code-style-conventions": "^0.2.0"
   },
   "autoload": {
      "classmap": [
         "database/seeds",
         "database/factories"
      ],
      "psr-4": {
         "App\\": "app/",
         "Modules\\": "Modules/",
         "App\\Doctrine\\Entity\\": "app/Doctrine/Mappings/App/Doctrine/Entity"
      }
   },
   "autoload-dev": {
      "psr-4": {
         "Tests\\": "tests/"
      }
   },
   "extra": {
      "laravel": {
         "dont-discover": [
            "nwidart/laravel-modules"
         ]
      }
   },
   "scripts": {
      "test": "phpdbg -qrr ./vendor/bin/phpunit",
      "tests-with-coverage": "php artisan common:create-phpunit-config && phpdbg -qrr -d memory_limit=-1 ./vendor/bin/phpunit --filter Unit --coverage-text --colors=never",
      "ci-flow": [
         "@composer validate --ansi",
         "@php artisan common:phpcs --ansi",
         "phpdbg -qrr -d memory_limit=-1 ./vendor/bin/phpunit --filter Unit",
         "phpdbg -qrr -d memory_limit=-1 ./vendor/bin/phpunit --filter Feature"
      ],
      "post-create-project-cmd": [
         "@php artisan key:generate"
      ],
      "post-autoload-dump": [
         "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
         "@php artisan package:discover"
      ],
      "post-update-cmd": [
         "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
         "php artisan ide-helper:generate",
         "php artisan ide-helper:meta"
      ]
   },
   "config": {
      "preferred-install": "dist",
      "sort-packages": true,
      "optimize-autoloader": true,
      "classmap-authoritative": true
   },
   "minimum-stability": "dev",
   "prefer-stable": true,
   "repositories": [
      {
         "type": "composer",
         "url": "https://mysite"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was because I was using the root directory during testing. I don't know why php artisan (a part of my composer.json) doesn't like it but it solved the problem.